# How can I ensure that each case defined in an enum class is treated, e.g. using static_assert?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Assume an `enum class`

```
enum class MY_ENUM {FOO, BAR};
```

and a `std::map` which holds some information about each element in the enum

```
map<MY_ENUM, MyInfoType> enumInfos;
```

How can I ensure at compile time that for each value of the enum there is an entry in the map?

I would like to be able to write something like (of course this code is not valid):

```
for (auto& elem : MY_ENUM) {
    static_assert(enumInfos.find(elem) != enumInfos.end(),
        "Error: Information for an element in MY_ENUM is missing.")
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This is not possible to check it at compile time as you fill in the map in a runtime...

Comment: Is that true also for a static const map?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to define `enumInfos` as a type trait instead? Something like `template <MY_ENUM E> struct enumInfos;`, then specialized like `template <> struct enumInfos<MY_ENUM::FOO> { ... };`.

Comment: @user2296653 Even if it's `const` it doesn't matter. `const` here means immutable. So the fill is still done at run-time, as `map` itself is not considered a candidate for compile-time expressions.

Comment: @user2296653, yes, a static const map still needs to dynamically-allocate memory for the elements on the heap, which can't happen at compile-time.

Comment: @TartanLlama I guess that would enforce using templates whenever one wants to access the information, won't it? So I could e.g. not write a non-template function `getEnumInfo(MY_ENUM enum)` unless I cover every possible value inside that function explicitly, which leads to the same problem as described in my original question. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: If you need runtime access to the info, you could write a switch statement. With the right compiler warnings turned on and warnings treated as errors, you'll get a compiler error if you forget to handle an enum value in the switch (so long as you don't define a default case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `std::map` you could write an information retrieval function which uses a `switch` statement to get the right information. Many compilers will present you with a warning if you miss an enum value in a `switch`, so you could turn on the necessary warnings in your compiler, treat warnings as errors, then you would get a compiler error if you forget a value. For example, here is how GCC treats the following:

```
enum class MyEnum { Foo, Bar };

using MyInfoType = std::string;

MyInfoType getEnumInfo (MyEnum e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case MyEnum::Foo: return "Foo";
    }
    return "";
};
```

> error: enumeration value ‘Bar’ not handled in switch

Comment: Beware! a `std::string` cannot be constructed with `0`, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: no, it is not possible. That's because a `std::map` cannot be built at compile time: it [doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), and has a non-trivial destructor.

As to why `map` is a challenge to implement in a `constexpr` manner, it is probably because it uses dynamic memory allocation by its default [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). If somehow will be possible to construct a compile-time allocator ([which may be](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/embedded/2014-October/000138.html), in C++ never say never), then it may be possible to have a `constexpr` map.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++14 there's a way to check at compile time if an enum value have a `MyInfoType` associated but my approach requires `MyInfoType` to be a [Literal Type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType) in order to create a `constexpr` instance of it; I've tried with this definition:

```
struct MyInfoType
{
    int stuff{};
    char name[20]{};
    constexpr bool operator !=(const MyInfoType &mit) const
    {
        return stuff != mit.stuff && name != mit.name;
    }
};

constexpr MyInfoType UNKNOWN{-1, "UNKNOWN"};
```

There's a `MyInfoType` instance named `UNKNOWN` which should be the value associated by default to the enum values, this could be achieved with variable templates:

```
template <MY_ENUM VALUE> constexpr MyInfoType MY_ENUM_INFO = UNKNOWN;
template <             > constexpr MyInfoType MY_ENUM_INFO<MY_ENUM::FOO>{0, "FOO"};
template <             > constexpr MyInfoType MY_ENUM_INFO<MY_ENUM::BAR>{1, "BAR"};
```

If the variable template `MY_ENUM_INFO` is used with a value different from `FOO` or `BAR` it will have the `UNKNOWN` value; and all the values of `MY_ENUM_INFO` are `constexpr` so we can check at runtime for its validity with a variadic template:

```
template <typename ENUM> constexpr void Check() {}

template <typename ENUM, ENUM VALUE, ENUM ... VALUES> constexpr void Check()
{
    static_assert(MY_ENUM_INFO<VALUE> != UNKNOWN, "Unknown enum value");
    Check<ENUM, VALUES ...>();
}
```

The `Check` function should be called somewhere though, in my <kbd>[Live Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fbfvzHWlru6J4X7P)</kbd> I've called it on `main`:

```
int main()
{
    Check<MY_ENUM, MY_ENUM::FOO, MY_ENUM::BAR>();
    return 0;
}
```

Let's suppose we add a new value to `MY_ENUM`:

```
enum class MY_ENUM {FOO, BAR, BAZ};
```

And we forgot to associate the `MyInfoType` on the variable template specializations, then if we compile the `Check` function this way:

```
Check<MY_ENUM, MY_ENUM::FOO, MY_ENUM::BAR, MY_ENUM::BAZ>();
```

The compiler complains about `BAZ` being an `"Unknown enum value"`:

> error: static assertion failed: Unknown enum value
>
> ```
> static_assert(MY_ENUM_INFO<VALUE> != UNKNOWN, "Unknown enum value");
> ```

This approach is far from being perfect, it requires to maintain separately the enum, the variable template specializations and the call to `Check` function so, if you forgot to update the call to `Check` after adding a new enum value all the effort is useless. But if you're methodic it can help you to ensure that each case defined in an enum class is treated, validated by `static_assert`.

#### Edit

Regarding to the comments...

> ...it could be a nice solution but has a severe restriction: you cannot have run-time access to the information

My bad, I didn't get that you need to check `MyInfoType` association with `MY_ENUM` at compile time AND access in runtime, but this is not a problem at all; with few changes is easy enough to build the map at runtime:

```
template <typename ENUM> constexpr void Populate(std::map<ENUM, MyInfoType> &) {}

template <typename ENUM, ENUM VALUE, ENUM ... VALUES> constexpr void Populate(std::map<ENUM, MyInfoType> &m)
{
    static_assert(MY_ENUM_INFO<VALUE> != UNKNOWN, "Unknown enum value");
    m.emplace(VALUE, MY_ENUM_INFO<VALUE>);
    Populate<ENUM, VALUES ...>(m);
}
```

Now that whe have the `Populate` function (previously named `Check`) we have no excuse to forget the call which checks the enum values and populates the map:

```
std::map<MY_ENUM, MyInfoType> values;

int main()
{
    Populate<MY_ENUM, MY_ENUM::FOO, MY_ENUM::BAR>(values);

    for (const auto &v : values)
        std::cout << v.second.name << '=' << v.second.stuff << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This approach isn't perfect (neither the previous one) because it still relies on the programmer hand to update the call to `Populate` and create the new `MY_ENUM_INFO` specializations but IMHO is and approach worth to mention.

> would have to introduce templates wherever you want to use the information

I don't get why this is a problem, you're introducing templates anyway wherever you want to use a container; whe shouldn't be afraid to use templates, only be aware to use them wisely.

Comment: I guess this could be boiled down quite a lot to somethig similar to the type trait approach suggested by TartanLlama in a comment to my question. Then it could be a nice solution but has a severe restriction: you cannot have run-time access to the information and would have to introduce templates wherever you want to use the information.

Comment: @user2296653 I don't get why you're reluctant to introduce templates, after all you're using many of them from the stl.

Answer (score 0):

In case your enum is numbered from 0 up with one per step each you could do:

```
enum MY_ENUM {FOO = 0, BAR, LAST_ITEM};

MyInfoType allInfos[LAST_ITEM];
```

This way you an array covering all possible values. `LAST_ITEM` must stay the last item in the enumeration as it defines the number of elements.

Comment: 1. I would prefer to use an enum class instead of a plain enum, and 2. Your way does not ensure that there actually is information stored in the array (e.g. if `MyInfoType` is something with a default constructor like `std::string`).

Comment: The default constructor should be called for each element in my case.